# Using binding with converter in Header property of DataGridTextColumn in WPF not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
   <converters:KindConverter x:Key="KindConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Visibility="{Binding IsTableVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
          CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
          Margin="5,30,5,5" FontSize="16">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Year" Binding="{Binding Year}" Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Kind, Converter={StaticResource KindConverter}}" Binding="{Binding Count}" Width="*"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The `Items` is an `ObservableCollection<MyModel>` (but works for `List<..>` too when display data to datagrid)

```
public sealed class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _kind;

  public MyModel(string year, string kind, int count)
  {
    Year = year;
    Kind = kind;
    Count = count;
  }

  public string Year { get; }
  public string Kind { get { return _kind; } set { _kind = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Kind)); } }
  public int Count { get; }

  ...
}
```

and the converter:

```
public sealed class KindConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return $"Number of {value}"; // I put breakpoint but is not reached
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I add data like:

```
Items.Add(new MyModel("2019", "Movies", 3);
...
```

but the header in column is not displayed, it seems to be empty. I expected to see `Number of Movies`.

[image]

Comment: What specific `Count` value do you expect to see in the header? There is one count per row...

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question you want to have a dynamic header based on the Kind property of your models in an observable collection. The only problem is that you are binding the header of a datagrid that is bound to your datacontext probably; so you are binding to the Kind property of the datacontext of your datagrid that probably doesn't exist. What are you trying to achieve is "logically" wrong because you can have multiple objects that have different Kind property so what should you want to have in your datagrid?

If you want to group the models by the Kind property you have to create a CollectionViewSource with GroupDescriptions and bind it to the ItemsSource of your DataGrid.

Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control) to see how it works.

Hope this can help